# Autosizer making a div of height and width 0

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

My configuration goes as follows:

```
// Calling it
<div style={{ width: 1000, height: 800 }}>
  <MyComponent />
</div>

// MyComponent.js
<InfiniteLoader { ...itsProps }>
  {({ onRowsRendered }) => (

    <AutoSizer>
      {({ width, height }) => (

      <Table
        width={ width }
        width={ height }
        ...
```

The problem is that this is what is being rendered:

```
<div style="overflow: visible; height: 0px; width: 0px;">
  <div class="ReactVirtualized__Table" role="grid">
    ...
```

So nothing is seen in the screen.

Maybe I misunderstood `Autosizer` usage, so I set it up to adjust itself to the parent's width/height.

What am I missing?

Comment: can you provide more from output html

Answer (score 8):

The `height: 0` style in the snippet of HTML you shared isn't actually a problem, because of the `overflow: visible` style. This is the way `AutoSizer` is meant to work.

I suggest you read the ["Using `AutoSizer`" docs page](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/usingAutoSizer.md). I suspect your problem is similar to one of the common issues mentioned there:

> `AutoSizer` expands to fill its parent but it will not stretch the parent. This is done to prevent problems with flexbox layouts. If AutoSizer is reporting a height (or width) of 0- then it's likely that the parent element (or one of its parents) has a height of 0. One easy way to test this is to add a style property (eg `background-color: red;`) to the parent to ensure that it is the correct size. (eg You may need to add `height: 100%` or `flex: 1` to the parent.)